# proper usage of 'if not in' python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm working through project euler problems, specifically problem 23:
[image]

So I figured out a solution in python but it was running very slowly and I realized that I was storing multiples of the abundant sums in a list. I tried to prevent this by adding a 'not in' but for some reason adding this single line changed my answer completely. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
for i in range(13, 28123):
    s = sum_divisors(i)
    if s > i:
        abundant_numbers.append(i)

check_list = list()

for i in abundant_numbers:
    for j in abundant_numbers:
        s = i + j
        if s <= 28123 and s not in check_list:  # only check when sum < 28123 and prevent duplicates
            check_list.append(s)
        else:
            break

check_list.sort()
sum_ans = 0

for i in range(28123):
    if not binary_search(check_list, i):
        sum_ans += i

print 'sum', sum_ans
```

When I leave it as just

```
if s <= 28123
```

it works fine. The problem only occurs with the 'not in' condition.

Comment: It would be great if you could post full code (sum_divisors is not defined).
What could be even greater, especially for you, is that learning hard way (on mistakes) is very very rewarding. BTW your this triple loop (abundant number x 2 then another asking if something is in list) is super slow O(n^3).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text

Comment: @mata Sorry, I didn't know I wasn't supposed to do that!

Comment: @AlexBaranowski yeah the solutions below helped figure out what was wrong with what I was doing. The triple for loop certainly also wasn't ideal but was just to see if that was the cause of the problem. Using a set sped things up though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a completely different result because adding `not in` means the `break` is now conditioned also on a membership in `check_list`:

You should probably be doing:

```
if s <= 28123:
    if s not in check_list:
        check_list.append(s)
else:
    break
```

You can avoid doing the membership check altogether and just make `check_list` a **set**:

```
check_set = set()
for i in abundant_numbers:
    for j in abundant_numbers:
        s = i + j
        if s <= 28123:  
            check_set.add(s)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: breaking up the if statement actually didn't work but sets did! Didn't think to do that so thanks!

Comment: @greenteam Updated the answer

Comment: It did not work because He was checking the `not in` condition first. He reversed it and it works now.

Comment: @greenteam. And keep in mind that using `set`s is not response-neutral, since a set is an *unordered* collection of items.

Comment: @Kanak They're sorting afterwards, so I don't think the ordering is a problem here

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you do

```
... 
        if s <= 28123 and s not in check_list:
                check_list.append(s)
        else:
            break
...
```

It breaks once `s` is either greater than 28123 or it is in `check_list`. And, the fact that `s` is in `check_list` is very likely to occur before it is greater than 28123.

To prevent this, you may want to relocate your `s not in check_list` boolean, like so

```
... 
        if s <= 28123:
                if s not in check_list:
                    check_list.append(s)
        else:
            break
...
```